# How to double line any node shape in Mermaid

Tags: css, mermaid

Mermaid node shapes allow to double only circles with `ID1(((Text)))`, but I need to create a double lined rhombus, and maybe a double lined square to.

I know that it's possible to write CSS code in Mermaid, but I don't find any solution to my problem.

[This is the result that I want, but I want it with rhombus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Kvd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible.  You would need to request support for a new shape at : https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues